# Craft changing/corrupting assets on download?

Tags: assets, download

I have a problem with downloading files from Craft CMS using the "download asset" action on the asset page in the control panel.

These files don't have a public URL and needs to be downloaded this way.

If I check the SHA256 hash of the uploaded file in the asset's folder, it is correct. But when downloading it I get a different hash and in cases of .exe and .zip-files also corrupting and making them unable to run. The zip-files can't be unzipped.

Why does this happening?

Answer (score 1):

**Found the problem in index.php**

The reason why this happened was that the `index.php` file had, by mistake, one space indentation. the download stream adds those extra spaces and making the files corrupt.